# EditorFor parameters in Action MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

Having a bit of trouble figuring something out.

I've got an Action:

```
public ActionResult FareTypeSelector(SearchTypes searchType, SearchSource searchSource)
        {
            IFareTypeOptionsRepository fareTypeOptionRespoitory = new FareTypeOptionsRepository();

            FareTypeOptions fareTypeOptions = fareTypeOptionRespoitory.GetFareTypeOptions(searchSource, searchType, _authentication.UserLoggedIn.CallCentreUser, _authentication.UserLoggedIn.AgencyProfile.BranchCode);
            return View();
        }
```

I've created an *'Editor'*, i.e. a file in *EditorTemplates* called *FareTypeSelector.cshtml*.

I want to bind my editor to a property of the model of the page that contains the editor. But I also want to pass some parameters into my action, i.e. `(SearchTypes searchType, SearchSource searchSource)`. The idea being that the data displayed in the editor is based on this information passed in. Now I can't quite figure out if:

1. Is this possible?
2. whats the markup needed in the main view to render
   this, pass the parameters and bind the resulting selected value into the main model?

Ta in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EditorTemplates are used for Data items from your model, not Action methods.  They're using only in your view to render a specific model (or member of a model)

Comment: thought that might be the case. is there anything else I can bind to my model that will accept some parameters? I want to load this via Jquery eventually you see so I want the values to change.

Comment: @Liam - you're not passing any model to your view.  Without a model, there's nothing an editor template can do.

Comment: OK ta, I need to re-think this I think